# php shopping cart array help

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an php array:

```
Array ( [1] => Array 
    ( [qty] => 3
      [material] => 2 
      [size] => 4 
     ) )
```

the first value 1 is the productid.

I would like to be able to add qty (to the existing value) based on the condition that the same material and size is selected. if the material or size is not the same then a new array is created, adding to the existing one.

Alternatively is there a better way of doing things?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you keying it by product ID if there can be multiple entries per product ID? Just make the product ID one of the properties like qty/material/size and search the array when updating quantity. It's not like shopping cart arrays are going to grow so large that a linear search will be slow.

Comment: If 1 is the product id, then it wouldn't be possible to add another one with the same product id without overwriting the existing size and material. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming array = $foo and the others are stored in:, $id,$material,$size

```
if(is_array($foo[$id]) && $foo[$id]'material']==$material && $foo[$id]['size']==$size){
$foo[$id]['qty']=$foo[$id]['qty']+1;
//or it $qty could be other than 1
$foo[$id]['qty']+=$qty;
}
```

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for the responses, Dan and Francois makes very good points, I have modified the structure of the array, and have used the code from Dagon as a starting point and all seems to be working.

Thanks